# Exporting large array variables (type = object) to CSV files

Tags: python, gekko

I have used Gekko from APM in Python to solve an optimization problem. The two main decision variables (DVs) are large arrays. The problem has converged successfully, however, I need the results of these tables in an excel worksheet for further work.

An example variable name is `'s'`. Since the arrays created within `Gekko` are GKVariable/Object variable types I cannot simply use:

`pd.DataFrame(s).to_csv(r'C:\Users\...\s.csv')`

because the result gives every cell of the array the label of each variable defined in the model (i.e. v1, v2, etc.)

Using `print 's'` within the kernel will show the numbers of the array from the optimization results but in a format that doesn't guarantee that each line is a new row of the matrix because of the many columns.

Is there another solution to copy just the resulting value of the DV 's' so it becomes a normal `np.array` instead of the object type variable? Open to any ideas for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ``` s[i].value[0]`` for steady state problems ( ```IMODE=1`or`IMODE=3`) or`s[i].value[:]``` to access the array of values for all other [IMODE options](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Modes). Here is a simple example with writing the results to a file with pandas and numpy.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Random 3x3
A = np.random.rand(3,3)
# Random 3x1
b = np.random.rand(3,1)

# Ax = b
y = m.axb(A,b)
m.solve()

yn = [y[i].value[0] for i in range(3)]

print(yn)
pd.DataFrame(yn).to_csv(r'y1.csv')
np.savetxt('y2.csv',yn,delimiter=',',comments='')
```